# Unidentified Property; Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, html, web

[image: This is What I tend to see when I try to run it!]

Hi. I've been trying to create a PHP page using Savant Templating Engine that performs some CRUD operations via XAMPP. As I coded the page and tried to run the page, I found the above errors that showed up. But as I inserted the values into the textbox and textarea respectively and hit the publish button, I found that the database is being updated successfully. What is the probable reason for the above issue? And How do I get out of the problem.
I tried to search for existing threads regarding the same, but none of them seemed to address my problem. Please do help out citing the link below if any of the existing threads addresses my issue. Thanks. :)

-------------------------------------------------------------update--------------------------------------------------------------
view.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Create Post: Blog: Design & Social Media</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="../../applications/create/index.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $this->b->title; ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Publish" />
            <br/>
            <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="content"><?php echo $this->b->content; ?></textarea>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    include_once ('../../classes/models/blog.php');
    include_once ('../../resources/libraries/savant3.php');
    $s=new savant3();
    $s->method=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $b=new blog();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET")
    {
    }
    else
    {
        $b->title=$_POST['title'];
        $b->content=$_POST['content'];
        Blog::create($b);
        header('location:../../applications/success/index.php');
        return;
    }
    $s->display('view.html');
?>
```

Blog.php

```
<?php
    class Blog
    {
        public $id;
        public $title;
        public $content;
        public $created;

        public static function create(Blog $b)
        {
            $title=$b->title;
            $content=$b->content;
            $m=new mysqli("localhost","root","","kartik_iyer");
            $s=$m->prepare("insert into blog values(null,?,?,null)");
            $s->bind_param('ss', $title, $content);
            $s->execute();
        }

        public static function readSingle($id)
        {
        }

        public static function readAll()
        {
        }

        public static function update(Blog $b)
        {
        }

        public static function delete($id)
        {
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you except some debug from us without any sample of code ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'm editing it and putting in the code.

Comment: @ikartik: Text is preferred over screenshots for error messages. The image is unnecessary. Make sure your [sample code](http://sscce.org/) is complete yet concise.

Comment: Screenshot does not help, code does. Can only tell you that $b on line 10 of view.php has is not an object but your probably noticed that yourself.

Comment: @outis Thanks for the suggestion. I'll see to it that the next time I post a query, I prefer to use text over images.

Comment: I don´t know Savant, but it seems that `$this->b` does not exist, so I would start with a `var_dump($this)` and perhaps a `var_dump($b)` in the view to see where your variables are located.

Comment: @Roel: I've uploaded the code now in an update. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this messages because your error reporting is set to `-1` = `error_reporting(-1);` or at least the notices are enabled. This means, that all possible error messages get displayed, especially the notices, that usually are not enabled. I just recently asked about error reporting in **[this topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104818/how-important-are-php-notices-really)**.
Conclusion was, that you should write your code to fit the highest standards, but you shouldn't fix somebody existing code.

I would recommend to find the line, that is setting error reporting to `-1` remove it. Or override it with: `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);`. This will set it as default.

Or you can optimize your code with `empty()`, `isset()` and or presetting some variables to `NULL`.

Anyways, read [my link on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104818/how-important-are-php-notices-really) and you will understand the need-to-know-basis about error reporting.

Comment: Where do I find the line that you've specified?

Comment: @ikartik90: I don't know that, as I don't have access to your framework. One way is to search in your editor for "error_reporting". Also it might be, that your server is setup like that.. Though that's unusual.

Comment: Np, keep in mind, that if your variable = false, then its still set.. And isset checks whether the variable exists and that it is not NULL. So you wouldn't set something to false and wonder, why isset is allowing to pass.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. :) Though I already read the PHP manual... ;)